# Can knitr respect message(..., appendLF = FALSE) calls?

Tags: r, knitr

Is there any way to have knitr respect messages that don't end with line breaks? I haven't found a hook that governs this behavior, maybe I just missed it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<>>=
do_stuff <- function() {
  message("Doing some stuff...", appendLF = FALSE)
  message("done.")  
}
do_stuff()
@

\end{document}
```

The result includes a line break between the first and second messages, but if you run it in R there is no such break.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in **knitr**, and I just [fixed it](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/c2f4536f9901f7a4e9631f0370c5e02782524743) in the development version 1.16.2. You can install it via `devtools::install_github('yihui/knitr')`.